# Visual Studio 2019 not showing projects under Solution in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Created new Project in Visual Studio 2019, but its not showing under the solution and says '0' projects next the the solution..  Is there any settings?

[image]

Tried to add back the project, throws error:

[image]

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk) from super user.  Look down to the solution with 94+ points.  Have you already tried that?  I could re-post that answer but it always feels like stealing to me.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It worked! 

Comment: AWESOME!  I love it when a plan comes together.